# How to enable auditing for a folder only (and not anything within that folder)

Tags: security, windows-server-2008-r2, permissions

I am trying to track down a process responsible for resetting ACLs on a particular folder, and ONLY that folder, not any of the 10,000 folders and files it contains.

I tried going to Properties > Security > Advanced > Auditing to add auditing there, without checking the "Replace all existing auditing entries on all descendants...".  When I apply the auditing, the Security Log clearly shows the ACL being changed on descendant files, and I see auditing events for those files in that log.

I also tried the PS script here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/bulentozkir/archive/2009/12/26/bir-dizinde-folder-everyone-i-in-auditing-i-aktif-eden-rnek-powershell-scripti.aspx

But the results were the same.

Answer (score 0):

On the Auditing page, when you add the Auditing entry, make sure for `"Apply onto:"` you select

`"This folder only"`

and not the default

`"This folder, subfolders and files"`.

Also, select `"Apply these auditing entries to objects and/or containers within this container only"`

Comment: I gave it a shot, but when I choose `"This folder only"`, `"Apply these auditing entries ..."` becomes greyed out and unchecked.  After I apply the settings, I'm still getting auditing entries in the System Log.

Comment: Can you check a subfolder if the auditing entry is there? I haven't got the entry on a subfolder, so works as expected from my point of view?

Comment: I checked the subfolders and files, and the auditing entries are not there, yet in the logs I get `"An operation was attempted on a privileged object"` followed by the name of any individual files that I try to open or edit.  These log entries do not show up when I remove auditing from the top-level folder I originally applied the auditing to.

Comment: Weird... Then I haven't got any idea what's wrong, sorry :(